# Why my preg_match() is not working?

Tags: php, regex, syntax, preg-match

I have tried the following preg_match, and it worked for the very first time on the local machine, and then I uploaded the file on server, and it never worked, so I checked it back on the local machine, and it's not working on the local machine as well.
So is my preg_match syntax correct?
I want to check if the sentence contains atleast a letter (either uppercase or lowercase) or a digit anywhere in it.

```
if(preg_match([a-Z 0-9], $_POST['textArea'])){

    //do something

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add delimiters. That is, you must enclose the pattern within php delimiters.

```
if(preg_match('~[A-Za-z0-9]~', $_POST['textArea'])){

 // do something

}
```

For atleast a letter and a digit.

```
preg_match('~^(?=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])~', $_POST['textArea'])
```

Comment: It worked for me, thanks that you mentioned delimiters, and I found it on google, that all the PCRE functions must be enclosed within delimiters — http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php  I used slashes instead of tildes. Thanks for your help. Can you also suggest me an easy to learn tutorial on regex expressions in php and jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for a case insensitive match also in php the first argument needs to be passed as a string

```
if(preg_match('#a-z0-9#i', $_POST['textArea'])){
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**
for at least one charcter use `"/[a-z0-9\\s]+/"`

```
if(preg_match( "/[a-z0-9\\s]*/i", $_POST['textArea'])){
// do something

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
if(preg_match([a-zA-Z0-9]+, $_POST['textArea'])){
           //do something
}
```

This should tell you to search for any lower case letter, any upper case letter, or any number and see if you can find it one or more times.

Comment: you could also try:  ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}$  Any word of at least one letter or number